# C: better way to do sizeof(((SomeStruct *) 0)->some_member)?

Tags: c, ffi

I want to get the size of a specific member in a struct.

`sizeof(((SomeStruct *) 0)->some_member)` works for me but I feel like there might be a nicer way to do it.

I could `#define SIZEOF_ELEM(STRUCT, ELEM) sizeof(((STRUCT *) 0)->ELEM)` and then use `SIZEOF_ELEM(SomeStruct, some_member)`, but I wonder whether there is already something better built-in.

My specific use-case is in hsc2hs (Haskell C bindings).

```
pokeArray (plusPtr context (#offset AVFormatContext, filename)) .
  take (#size ((AVFormatContext *) 0)->filename) .
  (++ repeat '\NUL') $ filename
```

Comment: What's wrong with this approach? It's nice enough. Standard offsetof() macro works the same way.

Comment: In C, if it looks grim, it is often right ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've got is about as clean as it gets if you can't guarantee you have a variable to dereference.  (If you can, then use just `sizeof(var.member)` or `sizeof(ptr->member)`, of course, but this won't work in some contexts where a compile-time constant is needed.)

Once upon a long, long time ago (circa 1990), I ran into a compiler that had '`offsetof`' defined using the base address 0, and it crashed.  I worked around the problem by hacking `<stddef.h>` to use 1024 instead of 0.  But you should not run into such problems now.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has the following in one of their headers:

```
#define RTL_FIELD_SIZE(type, field) (sizeof(((type *)0)->field))
```

I see no reason to do any different.

They have related macros for:

```
RTL_SIZEOF_THROUGH_FIELD()
RTL_CONTAINS_FIELD()
```

and the nifty:

```
CONTAINING_RECORD()
```

which helps implement generic lists in straight C without having to require that link fields be at the start of a struct.  See this [Kernel Mustard article](http://kernelmustard.com/2006/11/04/containing_record-for-fun-and-profit/) for details.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you've already got the correct solution there.  You could dig up your stddef.h and look for how offsetof is defined, since it does a very similar thing.

Remember that there may well be a difference between the sizeof a member and the difference between the offsetofs of that member and the next one, due to padding.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you could do sizeof(SomeStruct::some_member), but this is c and you have no scope resolution operator.  What you've written is as good as can be written, as far as I know.